# Rename output PDF files as subdirectory name recursively Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, output, rename, subdirectory

I'm pretty new to Powershell. Want to merge all PDF files subcategory (done). Next, I want to define a recursive name for my `$outputfile` that will consist of `subdirectory name + 'Additional Text'`. I am stuck in this point...

```
$pdftk = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe' 
$inputfolder = "C:\Tests" 
$outputfile = "combined.pdf"

dir $inputfolder -r -include *.pdf -exclude $outputfile | sort-object | 
group DirectoryName |   % {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name)\$outputfile" verbose}
```

I'm trying to use something like this line below. I don't know how to refer to $outputfile. How can I define a dynamic output name?

```
gci C:\Tests\*.*  | % { rename-item –path $_.Fullname –Newname ( $_.basename + (get-date -format ' Additional Text') + $_.extension)}
```

In directory `C:\Tests` there're folders `xx, yy, zz`. My code merges all files within each subdirectory and name it `combined.pdf`. Instead of combined.pdf I want to see a final file `xx.pdf` in `C:\Tests\xx` subdirectory, `yy.pdf` in `\\yy` and `zz.pdf` in `\\zz` :) Now I'm thinking how to use `$($currentfolder.FullName)\$outputfile` to achieve it.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you want the new filename(s) to be?

Comment: In directory `C:\Tests` there're folders xx, yy, zz. My code merges all files within each subdirectory and name it `combined.pdf`. Instead of combined.pdf I want to see a final file `xx.pdf` in `C:\Tests\xx subdirectory`, `yy.pdf` in `\\yy` and `zz.pdf` in `\\zz` :) Now I'm thinking how to use `$($currentfolder.FullName)\$outputfile` to achieve it...

Comment: `($_.Directory).Name` should give you xx, yy etc:
`gci C:\Tests\*.* -Recurse -Filter $outputfile | % { rename-item –path $_.Fullname –Newname (($_.Directory).Name + $_.extension) }` I've removed the get-date & additional text parts as they don't match what you'e asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of renaming, you could write the correct name during the initial creation of the file like this:

```
    & $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name)\$($_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf).pdf" verbose
```